# how to run multiple urls in jmeter and it should display on one screen

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-maven-plugin

i am new to jmeter. i would like to run multiple urls at one shot and display the results on one screen. finding hard to config urls through csv file and in jmeter.

my sample url:

```
http://10.56.34.67:7065/services/sample/2070
http://10.56.34.67:7065/services/sample1/2070
http://10.56.34.67:7065/services/sample2/2070
```

like this i have more thn 100 url to test it.

could you please tell me the format to store urls in csv file and how to config the csv file in jmeter?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your data here is your URLs.

So instead of using multiple samplers for each URL, you can go for CSV Data config and store all your URLs there and name the column as URL.
you can refer to this in your single http sampler as ${URL}.
[image]

Your CSV should look like this[image]

In Server name put **${URL}** and in the **Thread Group** check the **forever** check box

Comment: could please tell me the format to store the urls in csv file?

Comment: Its is text format. open notepad, add the data and while saving the file give name in double quotes "abc.csv" and save

Comment: what if we have headers in order to access urls. how to config those headers in jmeter?

Comment: If the headers for all the requests is same then you need to add a single HTTP Header Manager. else we need to send the headers also through CSV.

Answer (score 0):

It has simple as

1. Click Ctrl+0,Ctrl+1 which adds Thread Group and HTTP Request in side
2. In  HTTP Request add `${path}` to Path field
3. In Thread Group choose Loop Count Forever
4. Add CSV Data Set Config by right click on Thread Group -> Add -> Config Element
5. CSV Data Set Config parameters :

   a. Put the fileanme in Fileanme field

   b. Enter in Variable Names `path`

   c. Choose Recycle as False

   d. Choose Stop Thread as True
6. Click Ctrl+R (run)

It will go through all URLs and submit them sequentially

To view results you can add View Results Tree (Click Ctrl+9) and you will see all your requests/responses.

Comment: could please tell me the format to store the urls in csv file?

Comment: as is, each line different url

Comment: where can i find csv date set congif parameter?

Comment: what about the server ip and port column? do i need to fill it with ip and port ?

Comment: No. Try using my instructions

Comment: hmm okay let me try it

Comment: what if i have headers ? how to config those headers in jmeter along with urls?

Comment: Please ask new specific question for a more complex scenario

Answer (score 0):

You don't need CSV for this use case, the easiest way would be going for [__StringFromFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile).

1. In the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler put the __StringFromFile() function into "Path" input field like:

   [image: JMeter StringFromFile]

   The textual function representation is `${__StringFromFile(urls.txt)}`, you will need to replace `urls.txt` with full or relative path to the file where your URLs are listed
2. That's it, each time the request is called JMeter will read the next line from the file and substitute request path with the string from file:

   [image: JMeter StringFromFile]

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to get familiarized with JMeter Functions concept